# Cannot stop useEffect() from executing

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

My application, pulls data ( text, numbers) from a database and then places them in a canvas image. This is working as expected, and the data is being displayed along with a few lines of the final diagram. However the useEffect() function is not stopping and continues to display the same image, which I would not have realised had I not placed an alert. 
I have seen the documentation and other questions that have discussed this problem. I understand that I need to put a variable whose value will not change. But I am simply unable to do this. I am sharing my code. Will be grateful if someone can help.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import './cindex.css';
 
 
export default function GetChartData() {
 const params = useParams();
 const [dbdata, setData] = useState('empty52');
 const canvas = useRef();
 let ctx = null;
 let name = null
 let Lalong = null
 let T1 = { text: 'dummy', x: 180, y: 100 }
 let T2 = { text: 'dummy', x: 180, y: 200 }
 
 useEffect(() => {
   async function getData() {
   const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/getchartdata/${params.id.toString()}`);
   //const response = await fetch(`http://khona21.cleverapps.io/getchartdata/${params.id.toString()}`);
    
     if (!response.ok) {
       const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
       window.alert(message);
       return;
     }
     
     const dbdata = await response.json();
     setData(dbdata);
   }
   getData();
   return;
   },[dbdata]);
  
 // initialize the canvas context
 
  useEffect(() => {
    
    // dynamically assign the width and height to canvas
    const canvasEle = canvas.current;
    canvasEle.width = canvasEle.clientWidth;
    canvasEle.height = canvasEle.clientHeight;
    // get context of the canvas
    ctx = canvasEle.getContext("2d");
  //}, []);
  }, [T1,T2]);
 
 
 useEffect(() => {
     
   
   let pid = dbdata.pid;
   let spid = JSON.stringify(pid);
   if (typeof spid !== 'undefined'){
       name = dbdata.pid.name;
       Lalong = dbdata.GLon.La
       if (T1.text === 'dummy') {
           T1.text = name
           T2.text = Lalong.toString()
       }
       }
    else {
       //window.alert('undefined')
   } 
    
    drawLine({ x: 150, y: 20, x1: 150, y1: 450 });
    drawLine({ x: 300, y: 20, x1: 300, y1: 450 });
    
    writeText(T1);
    writeText(T2);
    window.alert('finished drawing')
    
  //}, []);
  //}, [[]]);
  }, [T1]);
  
 
      
  const drawLine = (info, style = {}) => {
    const { x, y, x1, y1 } = info;
    const { color = 'black', width = 1 } = style;
 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  // write a text
  const writeText = (info, style = {}) => {
  const { text, x, y } = info;
  const { fontSize = 20, fontFamily = 'Arial', color = 'black', textAlign = 'left', textBaseline = 'top' } = style;
 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.font = fontSize + 'px ' + fontFamily;
  ctx.textAlign = textAlign;
  ctx.textBaseline = textBaseline;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}
  
 return (
   <div>
     <h3>Chart Positions</h3>     
     <p>{JSON.stringify(dbdata)}</p>
     <hr></hr>
     <canvas ref={canvas}></canvas>
   </div>
 );
 
}
```

I have tried to ensure that that the text in T1 changes only once and hence should stop the loop. But it is not. What should I do?

Comment: T1 and T2 are initializating on every render, and they are objects, they are considered a different object on each render, so it keeps calling the useEffect.

Comment: Following your advice, I defined T1, T2, outside the function GetChartData() function. But If I do that, then the updated values do not reach the image-creating function. So please tell me where should I initialise them. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the TRICK was to use **[dbdata.length]** instead of simply *[dbdata]* as the stopping condition in the *useEffect()* function. *dbdata* was being set each time as new, but **dbdata.length** was not changing.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import './cindex.css';
 
 //let T1 = { text: 'dummy', x: 180, y: 100 }
 //let T2 = { text: 'dummy', x: 180, y: 200 }
 
export default function GetChartData() {
 
 const canvas = useRef();
 let ctx = null;
 
 const params = useParams();
 const [dbdata, setData] = useState('empty52');
 
 let name = null
 let Lalong = null
 const T1 = { text: 'dummy', x: 180, y: 100 }
 const T2 = { text: 'dummy', x: 180, y: 200 }
 
 useEffect(() => {
     
   async function getData() {
   const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/getchartdata/${params.id.toString()}`);
   //const response = await fetch(`http://khona21.cleverapps.io/getchartdata/${params.id.toString()}`);
    
     if (!response.ok) {
       const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
       window.alert(message);
       return;
     }
     
     const dbdata = await response.json();
     setData(dbdata);
     
     // *********************************************************************
   
   let pid = dbdata.pid;
   let spid = JSON.stringify(pid);
   if (typeof spid !== 'undefined'){
       name = dbdata.pid.name;
       Lalong = dbdata.GLon.La
       T1.text = name
       T2.text = Lalong.toString()
       }
    else {
       //window.alert('undefined')
   } 
    
    // dynamically assign the width and height to canvas
    const canvasEle = canvas.current;
    canvasEle.width = canvasEle.clientWidth;
    canvasEle.height = canvasEle.clientHeight;
    // get context of the canvas
    ctx = canvasEle.getContext("2d");
    
    drawLine({ x: 150, y: 20, x1: 150, y1: 450 });
    drawLine({ x: 300, y: 20, x1: 300, y1: 450 });
    
    writeText(T1);
    writeText(T2);
    window.alert('image drawn')
   
   // **********************************************************************
     
     
   }
   
   getData();
   
   return;
   },[dbdata.length]);
  
  
      
  const drawLine = (info, style = {}) => {
    const { x, y, x1, y1 } = info;
    const { color = 'black', width = 1 } = style;
 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  // write a text
  const writeText = (info, style = {}) => {
  const { text, x, y } = info;
  const { fontSize = 20, fontFamily = 'Arial', color = 'black', textAlign = 'left', textBaseline = 'top' } = style;
 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.font = fontSize + 'px ' + fontFamily;
  ctx.textAlign = textAlign;
  ctx.textBaseline = textBaseline;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}
  
 return (
   <div>
     <h3>Chart Positions</h3>     
     <p>{JSON.stringify(dbdata)}</p>
     <hr></hr>
     <canvas ref={canvas}></canvas>
   </div>
 );
 
}
```